# Asp.Net Core - inherit controller and its routes, but override the methods

Tags: api, asp.net-core, controller, routes, overriding

I have a generated controller using mvn which looks like this...

```
    public class TeamApiController : ControllerBase
    { 
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="teamID"></param>
        /// <response code="200">Success</response>
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("/api/Team/{teamID}/members")]
        [ValidateModelState]
        [SwaggerOperation("GetStaffMembersByTeamID")]
        [SwaggerResponse(statusCode: 200, type: typeof(TeamDetails), description: "Success")]
        public virtual IActionResult GetStaffMembersByTeamID([FromRoute][Required]int? teamID)
        { 
             // return null;
        }
    }
```

i want to inherit this controller and implement my own methods

```
 public class TeamImpController : TeamApiController
    {
        private readonly IStaffService staffService;
        public TeamImpController(IStaffService staffService)
        {
            this.staffService = staffService;
        }

        public override IActionResult GetStaffMembersByTeamID([FromRoute][Required]int? teamID)
        {
            // write my override method
        }
    }
```

everything compiles but when i run it get

```
AmbiguousActionException: Multiple actions matched. The following actions matched route data and had all constraints satisfied:
```

bascially i'm trying to inherit the routes of the generated file, but override the methods

Answer (score 0):

As I see here there is no need to inherit from TeamApiController as the two methods will have to different implementation with the same parameters also you can separate the implementation to the service or domain method and just call the implementation from the controller

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your `TeamApiController` as an `abstract` class, so that it's not recognized as a `Controller` itself. With that, you would need to move all the attributes to the derived class. So, your `TeamApiController` will become

```
public abstract class TeamApiController : ControllerBase
{ 
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="teamID"></param>
    /// <response code="200">Success</response>
    public virtual IActionResult GetStaffMembersByTeamID(int? teamID)
    { 
         // return null;
    }
}
```

And your `TeamTmpController` will become

```
public class TeamTmpController : TeamApiController
{
    private readonly IStaffService staffService;
    public TeamImpController(IStaffService staffService)
    {
        this.staffService = staffService;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("/api/Team/{teamID}/members")]
    [ValidateModelState]
    [SwaggerOperation("GetStaffMembersByTeamID")]
    [SwaggerResponse(statusCode: 200, type: typeof(TeamDetails), description: "Success")]
    public override IActionResult GetStaffMembersByTeamID([FromRoute][Required]int? teamID)
    {
        // write my override method
    }
}
```

If you have another controller that inherits from the `TeamApiController` and you need the base functionality. Simply call the `return base.GetStaffMembersByTeamID` or other methods as needed. I hope that helps.

**Note**: This is the tested approach that I have used in one of my projects. I have tested the above code as well, just to reverify that it works.